# ensuring that a value is set in api request with promise

Tags: ember.js

I do not think I am using promises correctly in the apiRequest function below. As you can see, the function apiRequest gets triggered by a `click` of a button. I assumed that the `clickToTrigger` function would block until the `apiRequest` has finished and  `todos` has been set, however, I sometimes get error message that `todos` is undefined in code that runs later on in clickToTrigger function. Is it possible that I have written the promise incorrectly. How should I write the apiRequest to ensure that the code (not displayed) in `clickToTrigger` won't run until the `todos` are set?

```
apiRequest: function(){
                        var that = this;
                        var datasource = 'http://example.com/api/todos';
                         return new Ember.$.ajax({url: datasource, dataType: "json", type: 'GET'}).then(function(data){  
                             that.set('todos', data);
                             }); 
                     },


 actions: {
     clickToTrigger: function(){
                         this.apiRequest();
                         todo = this.store.createRecord('index', {
                                          todos: this.get('todos'),                                                                           
                             });
                         todo.save();
                         //code moves on to do other things that need the todos but they are undefined...
                    }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `apiRequest` doesn’t block. If you want to wait on a promise to be resolved, you need to attach a `then` to it. Inside `clickToTrigger`:

```
this.apiRequest().then(function() {
  todo = this.store… // et cetera
```

I’m confused by your question, it’s not clear to me where exactly you want to wait for a promise to be fulfilled, but that’s the general pattern.

Comment: apologies. If you see OP where I call `todo.save()`. After that, I run some code (not shown in OP) that needs the information returned from api request, so if I do `this.apiRequest().then(function() {` I think problem should be fixed, but let me ask. If I do `this.apiRequest().then(function() {` do I still need to use the `then` inside the apiRequest?  i.e. use it twice? Your answer does not say that.